# Why the executable produced in "release " mode gives a bad result?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>


int maxComDiv(int mayor, int menor)
{
    int resto = mayor % menor;
    if (resto > 0) maxComDiv(menor, resto);
    else return menor;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "max comon divisor: " << maxComDiv(3654, 1365) << std::endl;
}
```

Using visual studio 2015 community update 2 --> fails in release mode. Well in debug mode.
Using mingw64 --> well in both modes.

Comment: If the condition `resto > 0` is true, what does the function return?

Comment: @JimmyB bad results SEEMS to indicate that the program gave a result, meaning that compilation succeded, then come my question : can different warnings level cause different  output code once compilation has been completed successfully ?

Comment: "It fails" is not an acceptable problem description.

Comment: Tell us what you mean by "fails". And what is the output of the executable in each case?

Comment: I apologize if I have expressed incorrectly. I do not speak English well . When I say that the executable fails mean that does not produce a correct result . In this case, the correct result is 21. vs2015-release mode: result is random.

Comment: As others have noted, you are seeing the effects of *undefined behavior* (UB). One should expect random results. If you happen to get the correct result it may be the (random) effect of an actual [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call): The result from the inner-most recursion is simply not overwritten until the outer most function call returns and thus happens to still be in the "function return value" storage and this way leaks to the caller. Still a bug by all means.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I'm learning C++ and such things confuse me. It would be good that the "undefined behavior" was consistent between the "debug" and "release" versions and (this is too much to ask) between different compilers.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of the program is *undefined* since the `return` value of `macComDiv` is *not* defined on all control paths.

I think you meant to write `if (resto > 0) return maxComDiv(menor, resto);`

(In C++ there is no implicit return value).

That accounts for the difference between your debug and release build.

Comment: I would add : first thing to check when your program run fine in debug but not in release is `undefined behaviour`

Answer (score 1):

You should read warning messages, uder gcc you would get:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int maxComDiv(int, int)':
prog.cc:11:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
```

which indicates missing return statement:

```
if (resto > 0) 
    return maxComDiv(menor, resto);
    ^^^^^^ ~~~~~~~~ !!
```

this causes Undefined Behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you enable release mode, the C++ compiler tries to optimize your code to make it run as fast as possible.

Furthermore it can't understand that `if(resto>0)` will call a recursive method and will **eventually** return false.

Since it sees that not all code paths in your method return a value(`if(resto>0)` doesn't return a value), it's giving you the error.

Comment: "that will eventually return false"?!

Comment: Since it will keep using the remainder in the method call, eventually `if(resto > 0)` will return false, since resto will be 0.

Comment: Ok, you mean that the *comparison* yields `false`, not the recursive method.